# Does gwt has any shuttle component

Tags: gwt

Hie i am looking for a shuttle component for my gwt app. the one which has two adjacent boxes.
and you can shuttle entries from left to right box to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have to list-box A and B, and a button that, when clicked, adds the selected elements of A to B.

AFAIK GWT has not such a built in widget, but you should be able to easily build one using just what I said: two list-boxes and one button :)

If you're looking for something fancier, you may want to have a look at [smartgwt](http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/) widgets, and particularly the [databound dragging example](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_db_dragging_featured_category).

Comment: quite surprised to hear that. but using whole new library just for one component that too again not the exact thing what i want would be wasting of resources...

Comment: I think GWT philosophy is to provide basic widget, that you can cobine to build more sophisticated ones. The widget you're looking for is actually a composite one, so you probably have to build it yourself.